# Paypal doesn't send IPN when counterparty status is Unverified or Unverified

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We build a web form for our client that enables payment using paypal in Singapore dollar ($) to a singapore paypal account. Now they're complaining that more than half of their client who had paid to them using paypal doesn't get the email notification that our system should send to them and the status of these clients in our system doesn't reflect the payment that these clients had made. It's clear here that on some cases, paypal doesn't send their IPN to our system.

From the transaction history csv file that our client gave to us (that they generated from their paypal account which is the receiving account in this case), most of the Status is Completed, but it seems our web site only receive IPN from paypal when the value for Counterparty Status is 'Non-US - Verified'. We won't receive IPN from paypal when the status is Completed but the counterparty status is either 'Non-US - Unregistered' or 'Non-US - Unverified'. So how do we solve this? How do we get those IPN from PayPal even if those payers are either unregistered or unverified? And actually what's the status of these payments?

Comment: The use of "our client/heir ... account" and "our web site" suggests there may be more than one system involved; are all payments going through exactly the same payment processing steps or are there different processes in different cases? If it is all one system and there are no differences for US and Singapore users (e.g. you are  definitely NOT giving/overriding the IPN HTML in the payments processing code for some users but not for other users) then you should contact PayPal support; the buyer's country or verified status should in no way cause IPNs to appear or be skipped.

Comment: Yup @geewiz all are using the same system. That's what puzzles me. I only get ipn from verified buyers. Paypal support haven't reply our email yet